# What is the identity element or neutral element for Route Concatenation?

Tags: scala, akka-http

The tilde, `~` is used to concatenate `Route`s in Akka HTTP. There may be other applications, but my motivating case is wanting to turn a collection of routes into a single route using the `~` operator.

To do this, it would be useful to have a "zero" element that could take the place of the `???` in the `foldLeft` example below:

```
val routes: Seq[Route] = ...
val route = routes.foldLeft[Route](???)(_ ~ _)
```

The needed zero would be the identity element for `~`, which would be a route that did nothing, just passed the request to the next route in the concatenation.  However, how can this be represented in code?

I found the `pass` and `Directive.Empty` directives, but both of those wrap an inner route and cannot be a route themselves.  They are Directives that can wrap a Route, while I need a `Route` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes in a concatenation chain continue processing so long as the the Routes reject the request.  If the first route rejects a request, the next is tried.  This continues until there are no more routes or a route accepts the request (ending the concatenation chain).

Given that, the identity Route you identify would need to *reject* every request.  [The built-in RouteDirective `reject`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/route-directives/reject.html#reject) does exactly this.  Your code becomes:

```
val routes: Seq[Route] = ...
routes.foldLeft[Route](reject)(_ ~ _)
```

Note: Your specific use case is already provided for by Akka HTTP.  Rather than needing to write the `fold` yourself, you can just use the built-in `RouteConcatenation.concat` as follows:

```
val routes: Seq[Route] = ...
val route = concat(routes: _*)
```